# Import function from dll in c# with ulong* parameter

Tags: c#, windows, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm developing in windows 7 and c# in visual studio 2015; 
i have a problem when i import a function used in a dll in my other c program:

```
unsigned long ulaVersion[2];
MHM_GetDLLVersion(ulaVersion);
cout << "MHM_1SL_interface.dll Version: " << ulaVersion[1] << "." << ulaVersion[0] << endl << endl;
```

In the header file :

```
unsigned long __stdcall MHM_GetDLLVersion(unsigned long *pulDllVersion);
```

the function works and print 1.8.

Well, now i try to use with c#

```
[DllImport(@"MHM_1SL_interface.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern UInt32 MHM_GetDLLVersion(ref UInt32 ulaVersion);
```

I try to use this but i have received "8" with result...
Where i'm wronging?
Which is the right method to pass the ulong* parameter to the function in c#?

Comment: It is an array, so the argument must be UInt32[], no ref.  Be sure to pass one that is already big enough with 2 elements.

Comment: Isn't a long 64 bits? If that's the case then maybe you need to swap out UInt32 for UInt64

Comment: @brandonstrong Not in C++ on Windows. There `long` is 32 bits.

Comment: @Hans Passant Of course it works..Thanks